# What are some Online Cloud Storage Services that can download files directly from the cloud?

Tags: google-drive-api, dropbox

What are some Cloud storage Services that can download files from web directly. 
For ex- I want to download a file -> www.example.com/god.avi
Now what are some cloud storage services that will allow me to directly upload the file to my account. 
Google Drive and Dropbox are cloud services but they dont have this facility.

Answer (score 0):

I assume since you're asking this question on Stack Overflow that you're asking this in the context of programming. In that case, Dropbox has the [Saver](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins/saver), which lets a user download a file directly to Dropbox. (Dropbox transfers the file from the URL server-side.)

Answer (score 0):

You can download/upload files pragmatically to [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/sdks/python) and also to [Google Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/). They have API to do it.

However, if you are really looking for really complete service where you can scale up your data storage until you want, you really want to take a look at Amazon S3. In fact, as far as I know, Dropbox works on the top of Amazon S3 to provide their services.

If you would like to have an idea about how to upload/download a file to Amazon S3, you can take a look to [this](https://github.com/CloudBees-community/tomcat7-hibernate-s3-clickstart) application example. If you want the same thing on Dropbox or Google Drive, there are a lot of examples on Internet. However, on these two providers you need a token to upload files, what I don't like. I prefer the way in which it works for Amazon S3 (just for programming purposes - GUI is better on GD or Dropbox).